# программа пропускает условную конструкцию

Tags: c, типы-данных

В этом кусочке кода стоят условия для ввода чисел 0>, но программа пропускает отрицательные числа, хотя при вводе нуля выдает нужный принт. Есть предположение, что дело в типе переменных, но если изменить их на тот же int, то в оставшийся код работать не будет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    size_t wdth, hght, lngth;
    printf("Введите высоту табуретки: ");
    scanf("%zu", &hght);
    if(hght<=0){
        printf("Высота должна быть больше 0.");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Введите ширину табуретки: ");
    scanf("%zu", &wdth);
    if(wdth<=0){
        printf("Ширина должна быть больше 0.");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Введите длинну табуреки: ");
    scanf("%zu", &lngth);
    if(lngth<=0){
        printf("Длинна должна быть больше 0.");
        return 1;
    }
    int model[lngth][hght][wdth];
    memset(model, 0, lngth * hght * wdth * sizeof(model[0][0][0]));
```

Comment: Я на си не пишу, но сильно подозреваю что `size_t` беззнаковый и по определению не бывает меньше нуля.

Comment: `size_t` - это по-сути `unsigned int`. Вы не можете ввести отрицательное число в этот тип данных. А на `int` поменять можно, только нужно ещё поменять `scanf("%d", &hght);`.

Comment: поменяйте `size_t` на `int` и будет работать так как вы хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить тип `size_t`. Тип `size_t` без знаковый, то-есть там нельзя хранить отрицательные числа. Он придуман для хранения размера который возвращает оператор `sizeof`. Он отрицательным не бывает. Вы можете заменить его на int, а после проверок введенных данных привести переменные к `size_t`. `(size_t) width`

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось size_t - беззнаковый тип данных, и все же придется поменять все на int.